# When is sum of squares a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, sums-of-squares, perfect-powers

Recall that $$\sum_{j=1}^nj^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$ When is this quantity a perfect square? It appears that the only solutions are $n=0,1,24.$ By setting $x=12n+6$, the problem reduces to finding rational points on the elliptic curve
$$
y^2=x(x+6)(x-6),
$$
but I do not know where to go from here. How can I show that these are the only solutions?

Comment: This is the [Cannonball Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CannonballProblem.html). The only positive integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=m^2$ are $(n,m)=(1,1),(24,70)$. One elementary solution can be found [here](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/vyuka/2010/semtc2/clanky/AnglinSquarePyramid.pdf) (by W. S. Anglin).

Comment: @user236182, please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/диофантовы-уравнения-суммы-последовательных-квадратов?страница=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Comment: Here is [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323911) to the Anglin's paper.